# Query required for inventory

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in which I have some inventory of Rooms available.

**HotelID**   **RoomID**   **InventoryDate**   **Qty**

600              12           2019-01-01      10

600              12           2019-01-02      10

600              12           2019-01-03      10

600              12           2019-01-04      10

600              12           2019-01-05      15

600              12           2019-01-06      15

600              12           2019-01-07      10

600              12           2019-01-08      20

600              12           2019-01-09      20

I required below result set

**HotelID**   **RoomID**       **StartDate**       **EndDate**       **Qty**

600              12           2019-01-01      2019-01-04     10

600              12           2019-01-05      2019-01-06     15

600              12           2019-01-07      2019-01-07     10

600              12           2019-01-08      2019-01-09     20

I am not sure from where to start. Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: I am looking for TSQL query. I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: So what's stopping you? We're not here to do your work for you. If you have a question, please ask one but ensure you show your efforts, explain your goals, and describe why your attempt(s) didn't work.

Comment: Almost the same exact question [2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269688/sql-server-query-calculate-availability-of-rooms)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select HotelID,RoomID,min(InventoryDate),max(InventoryDate),Qty
from tablename
group by HotelID,RoomID,Qty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate function to achieve this, in Your context MIN() and MAX() will cater to the requirement.

```
SELECT HotelID,RoomID,MIN(InventoryDate) as StartDate,MAX(InventoryDate) as EndDate,MAX(Qty)as Qty
FROM Tablename
GROUP BY HotelID,RoomID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get the desired output:

`SELECT hotelid, 
       roomid, 
       Min(inventorydate) AS StartDate, 
       Max(inventorydate) AS EndDate, 
       qty 
FROM   inventory_table 
GROUP  BY hotelid, 
          roomid, 
          qty`